# When does a special (non-green) die leave your die pool?

Tags: elder-sign

I just started playing Elder Sign, and the wording in the rule book made me think maybe there was some way to keep using the yellow/red die beyond the current turn, if it was unused. Is this the case?

Answer (score 3):

The [updated rules](http://www.fantasyflightgames.com/ffg_content/Elder%20Sign/support/SL05_ES_Revised_Rulebook.pdf) state:

> Unless dice are locked or secured by a spell, the player returns any
>   dice granted by common or unique items to the supply at the end of the
>   Resolution phase.